# null ResultSet exception

Tags: java, oracle, nullpointerexception, resultset

I want to connect to oracle and get some records.

```
java.sql.ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("Select * from table1");
while (r.next()==true) {
    System.out.println(r.getString("column1").toString());  
      }
```

table1 include like that rows

- row1  movieName1
- row2  movieName2
- row3
- row4  movieName2

I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"   error when I execute above code. How can I fix it ?

Comment: What are the columns in your table? Desc your table.

Comment: Which reference is null? Actually you don't need to call `.toString()` on a String reference.

Answer (score 4):

Well it looks like `column1` doesn't have a value for one row... so `getString()` is returning a null reference, which you're then calling `toString()` on - leading to the exception. As you're calling `getString()` the `toString()` call is pointless anyway, so you could rewrite it as:

```
while (r.next()) {
    System.out.println(r.getString("column1"));  
}
```

That will then print `null` instead. If you want to avoid that, use:

```
while (r.next()) {
    String name = r.getString("column1");
    if (name != null) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The return value of `r.getString("column1")` might be null, so you will get a `NullPointerException` on the subsequent `toString()` method call. You have to check for null values before you use the return value.
2. You don't need to to call `toString()` here. The `getString` method already returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where exactly in your code the exception occurs. The most likely causes are that `s` is `null` or that `r.getString("column1")` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you get nullpointer because row3 has null value and you're trying to "toString"-it

Answer (score 1):

If its the first line that you posted that throws the error my guess would be that the variable s is null (not initialized), but since you don't tell us exactly what line of your code throws the error its hard to tell.